# Css - Submenu disappears when tab is unhovered

Tags: css

I am on this problem for 24h now...

I try to fix a theme, to see the problem, go on : https://mysandbox.cf/
Hover the tab called "More", and then, you can see other tab called "Age", "Jeux", "Collections"... Under this, you can see a sub-sub menu (who shouldn't be displayed except if you hover Age, jeux or Collections)

I tried to fix the problem with this code (add it in browser console):

```
#category-92 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
}

li#category-92:hover > .popover {
    opacity: 1;
}

#category-20 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#category-20 .dropdown-item:hover ~ .popover{
    opacity: 1;
}

#category-162 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
}

#category-162 .dropdown-item:hover ~ .popover{
    opacity: 1;
}
```

It fixes the dropping action when hover tab, however, it disappears immediately if you unhover the tab. I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: Your link doesn't work

Comment: Oh, so sorry !  https://mysandbox.cf/

Answer (score 0):

I solved with :

```
#category-92 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 500px;
}

li#category-92:hover > .popover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

#category-20 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 500px;
}

li#category-20:hover > .popover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
}

#category-162 .popover {
    opacity: 0;
    margin-top: 500px;
}

li#category-162:hover > .popover {
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: -20px;
}
```